# user tracking if he stays within the geographical boundary

Tags: node.js

we have a requirement to update the value of the field in some collecion when user stays within the geographical boundary for more than some duration.For example if user stays within the geographical boundary for more than 5 minutes value in the database has to be updated.I m looking for efficient solution in Nodejs.I am not getting how to approach the problem.Mobile application will be constantly sending user's location to the node js server.
Tech stack
1.React native mobile application
2.Node js server
3.Mongo Database

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I can think of is of setting a central point and then consider the idea of tracking the user location within a circle of some fixed radius, with its center being the central point. Now, it gives us a problem of how to choose a central point.

The best way to do this is to consider the following scenario:

Suppose at a time, the server received the location **[x,y]**. Then, assuming the **radius to be r**, we can see if for the next 5 minutes the location received lies within the **circle of radius r, centered at [x,y]**. To prevent the server from overloading with locations, we can send the user location every half a minute or so. If for five minutes, the location remains in the circle. We can then save the location.

This is not an exact answer, but hopefully, it can be a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.somehow we managed to the geofence in the react native mobile application